# Do you know if there are any breaking changes for upgrading log4js from 1.1.1 to ^6.4.0?

Tags: javascript, logging

```javascript
if (config.log.format === 'logstash') {
  log4js.clearAppenders()
  log4js.loadAppender('logstash', appender)
  log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.logstash())
}

const logger = log4js.getLogger()
logger.levels = config.log.level

module.exports = logger
```

Upgrading from version 1.1.1 of log4js to ^6.4.0 put me in trouble. I read about some differences but can't figure it out. One thing to mention is that locally it doesn't complain about this error but it is complaining on jenkins pipeline. The error:

> log4js.clearAppenders()
> ^
>
> TypeError: log4js.clearAppenders is not a function
> at Object. (/usr/src/app/src/log/logger.js:6:10)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
> at Module.require (/usr/src/app/node_modules/require-in-the-middle/index.js:43:24)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
> at Object. (/usr/src/app/index.js:4:13)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
>
> Want to mention that the only thing I've changed is the way how the level needs to be set for logger. FROM `logger.setLevel(config.log.level)` ->
> `logger.level=config.log.level`

Comment: Have you read through the documentation and change logs?

Comment: [log4js Migration guide](https://log4js-node.github.io/log4js-node/migration-guide.html)

Comment: Yes, I read through the documentation. It fails on the first interaction with log4js, I mean log4js.clearAppenders() is the first usage.

Comment: upgrading by 5 major releases is bound to have at least a couple of breaking changes - and `clearAppenders` hasn't been a function since 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Which are the equivalents for the functions below in v6 log4js?

```
 log4js.clearAppenders()
 log4js.loadAppender('logstash', appender)
 log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.logstash())
```